# How to correctly enumerate files in selected path?

Tags: vb.net, file-io, iteration

Visual Studio 2008 (vb.net)
I made simple anivirus but when I make Full scan by this code:

```
FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = ("C:\")
    'first scan:************************************
    Try

        For Each strDir As String In
        System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)

            For Each strFile As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDir)

                ListBox1.Items.Add(strFile)

            Next
        Next

        'Start the timer:

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Timer1.Start()`
```

Just scan the first 6 files ...
I think the problem from Windows Folder permissions  (Windows - Program Files ...etc)
So how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
For Each strFile As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDir, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

**Edit:**

You could try the last solution found in this thread:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=624969

I tried this myself and it was super slow, but worked fine.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub foo(ByVal aDir As String)
        Try

            Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(aDir)
            Dim aryFiles() As IO.FileInfo = di.GetFiles("*.*")
            Dim aryDirs() As IO.DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()

            For Each fi As IO.FileInfo In aryFiles
                rslts.Add(fi.FullName)
            Next

            For Each d As IO.DirectoryInfo In aryDirs
                foo(d.FullName)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Stop 'the catch should be more specific
        End Try

    End Sub

    Dim rslts As List(Of String)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        rslts = New List(Of String)
        foo("C:\")
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(rslts.ToArray)
     End Sub
End Class
```

It looks like your solution essentially loops through the first folder it can find and stops there. This solution is a bit different as it will recursively go through all the files and folders based on the start location.

Comment: Add in new line or Replace this one: System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)

Comment: Still Not fixed , didn't scan this folders (Windows , Program Files ...etc)

Comment: You could probably make it handle this progressively on a separate thread to make the UI more responsive, but I haven't worked with VB in years so I wouldn't be sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

Put a `Console.WriteLine(ex)` in your catch block so you can see any exceptions that are thrown.  You'll probably see your problem then.  Most likely permissions.

Comment: Still not working: 
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex)
        End Try

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` may not be the correct thing to do, particularly if it's not a console application, but you need to do something to see what Exceptions, if any, you're hitting.  Even commenting out the `Try ... Catch` would help for debugging, but you should never just swallow an exception.